# CMake interprets directory paths as absolute in LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY vs. relative in RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I have two C++ projects on Ubuntu 18.04 with the most current VSCode, CMake For VisualStudio Code, CMake Tools extensions and cmake version 3.10.2.

Project `simc` with this line in its `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set_property(TARGET simc PROPERTY LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/home/paul/st/docker")
```

places produced library as expected in `/home/paul/st/docker` directory.

Project `ign-test` located in `home/paul/st/ign-test`, with this line in its `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set_property(TARGET ign-test PROPERTY RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "home/paul/st/ign-test")
```

places produced executable in `home/paul/st/ign-test/bin/home/paul/st/ign-test` directory, treating the `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` path as relative to its build directory. How to make that path absolute, behaving similarly to `simc` project?

Comment: Could it be missing `/` in front of `"home/paul/st/ign-test"`?

Comment: @blami Of course! Thank you.